# Why did Login Manager addon stopped working with Firefox 31 (maybe 30)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am using Firefox on Gentoo Linux with a modified version of https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/gnome-keyring-integration.
The modifications regard only the keys under which the logins are being stored and a compile issue with the C library.
The extension worked fine up to my latest update to FF 31. I do not know which version I used before because I don't pay too much attention to it. Updates are done whenever I update my system.

The symptoms: When I visit a login page for which credentials were saved, the login is autocompleted but the password is not.
I found that the findLogins function of the extension is called and returns the password in an nsILoginInfo structure.

So why does Firefox not fill the password in anymore?

**[Update 2014-09-06]**

So I did some more investigation on this issue:

- Installed various older versions via Gentoo's emerge: behaviour did not change.
- Installed FF 32 via emerge: Extension is not being used, error “Services.logins undefined” in the log console.
- Ran FF 32 and 31 from vanilla downloads: same behaviour as emerge-installs.

conclusion:

My add-on stopped working correctly on all versions up to 31 for unknown reasons.
The add-on is not even being called on FF 32.

I will try to write a minimal test login manager based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Creating_a_Login_Manager_storage_module and test it with FF 32. On success I will merge my old add-on into it.

**[Update 2014-09-07]**

The FF 32 problem was because of the missing `initialize` function (which was named `init` before). With changing this the add-on has the same symptoms as on any other version.

However, I tried https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/gnome-keyring-integration-1/ and it worked. I did not found out what's wrong with my old add-on. I changed the new one to fit my old keys and have a working solution now. It doesn't even need binary files. Maybe I will move it from the deprecated “libgnome-keyring” to “libsecret” some day.

Comment: That's odd. I would talk to the addon dev, he should be supporting all flavors of linux, maybe you can tell him how to get Gentoo into a VM and he can test it out. Otherwise you'll have to dig into it. Can Gentoo be VM'ed? Maybe I can check it out.

Comment: I don't think the original developer has time for this. He needed months for fixing the 64bit binary and is not really reachable for me.

Comment: I also do not think it has to do with Gentoo. I am using the binary Firefox builds (no compiling) and think that something in the addon API has changed so that I have to change the extension accordingly.
I only need a hint on how to gather more informations on this issue.

Comment: Ok maybe some user around here can test on their OS. Ill try to later today real busy right now.